# Calling data value into new SAS code / adding values from another table into a new table

Tags: sas

Hey guys thanks in advance for the help.

I'm trying to do a few things at once.

1. How do I call data values from another table that I have created?
2. How do I add the values from the beginnong to a specified value in my new table?

To elaborate, I have a column in table A that is based on members (from 1, 2, 3,.., 500). I have a new table that I want to create, table B, that should have a specific member number (5, 6, 8, etc.). For example, the corresponding value under 'Formulas' for the first row, should be the sum of the values from 1 to 5 from table A. Thank you so much!

Table A:

```
Members Value
1         3.4
2         4.8
3         5.1
4         6.2
5         3.8
6         2.1
```

Table B:

```
Members    Value
    3       13.3 (3.4 + 4.8 + 5.1)
    4       19.5 (3.4 + 4.8 + 5.1 + 6.2)
    6       25.4 (3.4 + 4.8 + 5.1 + 6.2 + 3.8 + 2.1)
```

This is the code I have so far:

```
data simulation_tracking; 
call streaminit(12345); 
    do Member_Count = 5,6,8,10,12,15,20,25,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,125,150,175,200,250,300,400,500;
        Formulas =  ;


    proc sql;
        create table claims.simulation_tracking as 
            select Member_Count,Formulas
        from simulation_tracking; 
    run;
```

Comment: Please post better sample data, primarily sample input and expected output.

Comment: hey Reeza, let me know if you need anything else. Thanks!

Comment: This looks like a running total? Is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So first let's convert your example data into an actual SAS dataset.

```
data have ;
  input member value;
cards;
1 3.4
2 4.8
3 5.1
4 6.2
5 3.8
6 2.1
;
```

We can use a SUM statement to generate the running sum of the VALUE variable.
You can then use the list of MEMBER ids that you want to control whether the observation is written to the output dataset.

```
data want ;
  set have ;
  running_total + value;
  if member in (3 4 6) then output;
 run;
```

This will create this table.

```
                          running_
Obs    member    value      total
 1        3       5.1       13.3
 2        4       6.2       19.5
 3        6       2.1       25.4
```

Comment: thanks Tom. say for example in the first SAS dataset that you have, let's say there is another column. How would you select that specific column?

Comment: How would you specify to do **what** with the extra column?  If it is not mentioned then it will have the value from the original observation just like the VALUE column does in the example.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a running total, then use RETAIN. 
I use the sum function which will ignore missing values in comparison to the sum operator.

```
data want;
set have;
retain running_total;
running_total= sum(running_total, value); 
if member_ID in (5,6,8,10,12,15,20,25,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,125,150,175,2‌​‌​00,250,300,400,500‌​) then output;
run;
```

Comment: what is 'have' in this case? the location of Table A?

Comment: Yes, this is a standard convention used in SAS examples. HAVE refers to the main input dataset that you already 'have'.

Comment: It says there is an error during the "running_total = sum()" line. Essentially I've done the following

Comment: data simulation_tracking;
Member_Count = {5,6,8,10,12,15,20,25,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,125,150,175,2‌​00,250,300,400,500} 
set claims.simulation; 
retain running_total running_total = sum(running_total, Member_Count); 
run;

Answer (score 0):

```
    data simulation_tracking;
    Member_Count = {5,6,8,10,12,15,20,25,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,125,150,175,2‌​00,250,300,400,500} 
    set claims.simulation; 
    retain running_total running_total = sum(running_total, Member_Count); 
    run;
```

Comment: What are you trying to actually do with this code?  Are the values 5,6,8, etc the values that you want to calculate the running total from?

Comment: yeah, essentially I want to create another table that has the values in Member_Count as the values of the rows, and then the column associated with them is a running total. The values from the running total come from a table that already exists and is located in 'claims.simulation'

Comment: So 5 would include values 1 to 5, 70 would include 1 to 70, 250 would include 1 to 250, etc.

Comment: You're missing semicolons. Not sure what the first line (member_count) is trying to do in the first place.